# Implementing super-type subtype correctly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

Below is a diagram of a database in which I am trying to determine the appropriate design for. Here are a few notes.

- Employees/managers are associated with customers.
- The **partyid** is a way to globally represent a person; customer, employee, manager. Does it need to propagate all the way down? Should it be a primary key in all tables or just the tables that represent an individual?
- Do the other tables such as **billing**, **reporting**, **credential**, etc tables need to have their own respective id's that are primary keys, e.g. **billingid**, **reportingid**, **credentialid**, etc?

Some notes about the interaction of the entities.

- *employees* have a *manager(s)* associated with them.
- *customers* have a *manager(s)* and possibly *employees* associated with them.
- *customers* and *employees* will need to report time *billed*.

[image]

Comment: Are your customers organizations or individuals? Can your employee be a customer? Even if it can, do you need it in the model as such?

Comment: @Damir The customer is an individual. The customer and employee are both associated with an organization (organization is field in the **party** table). That brought up a good point about the **customer** table though. The objects in the customer table really relate to an order which I have moved into said table. I have also removed the _employeeid_ as a primary key as there is no point in have two primary key's. I have updated the question and diagram to reflect these changes.

Comment: @Astron, I'd like to ask (off-topic) which software you used to create this diagram? It looks rather pretty...

Comment: @stakx Microsoft Visio Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table "party" doesn't look right. Compare to the source code from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466163/same-data-from-different-entities-in-database-best-practice-phone-numbers-exa/5471265#5471265).

In this kind of structure, the party id number does propagate downward, so to speak. It should usually be either a primary key or a foreign key in tables that store data about a person.

In your table "reporting", it looks like the primary key shouldn't be 'partyid'. That would allow only one row per employee, which I don't think you intended. (I could be wrong.) If I'm right about that, you might consider a `NOT NULL UNIQUE` constraint on {partyid, date}, and a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on a new column, 'reportid'. The tables "travel" and "performance" would probably reference 'reportid'. (But keep reading.)

There are places in your diagram where an entity gets an additional key: your company assigns a unique employee id number to its employees, for example. There's no theoretical reason you can't use 'employid' instead of 'partyid' from that point on to reference employees. But there *is* a practical reason you might not want to do that.  It increases the number of joins.

For example, if the tables "credential", "tool", "certification", "academic", and "compliance" referenced employee.employid instead of employee.partyid, you couldn't just join "compliance" and "party" to get the person's name. You'd have to join "employee", too.

> Do the other tables such as billing, reporting, credential, etc tables
>   need to have their own respective id's that are primary keys, e.g.
>   billingid, reportingid, credentialid, etc?

They need to have a primary key; the primary key doesn't necessarily have to be an id number. If there's an existing natural key, you have to identify it and declare it UNIQUE anyway.

The table "orders" should probably have only "orderid" as its primary key; use a foreign key reference to identify the customer. In some cases, it makes sense to rename columns. In the case of customers, it might make sense to call its key 'customerid' instead of 'parytid'. I'd create a domain, myself.

```
create domain PARTY_ID as integer not null;
```

Then, everywhere that needed a party id number, I'd use the domain instead.

```
create table customers (
    customerid PARTY_ID primary key references parties (partyid),
...
```

I'd prefer to see a table of managers, too. A reference to it would guarantee that manager.managerid would resolve to an actual manager, not just to any employee.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have updated the diagram based on your suggestions as they all seem ideal. Take a look and let me know if I am on track. When you say **"I'd prefer to see a tables of managers"**, do you mean move the **manager** table out from under the **employee** table and under the PartyType category? My only concern with that is the _managers_ will no longer have the **employee** table attributes applied to them.

Comment: No, I just meant a table of current (probably) managers: could start as a single-column table to store the id numbers of all the employees who are actually managers. That table would be the target of any foreign-key constraint that needs a manager's id.