# One MySQL table with more foreign key parents, or more tables with one parent?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a huge database with many kinds of elements, so I have a few tables with the data. Something like the following:

```
Table1
-name
-number
Table2
-name
-address
-number
Table3
-address
-state
-color
```

Now I'm trying to create another table with links out of my database. Every link has the same attributes (title,url,element), but can be connected to any of the elements. Is it better to use one table for all links and determine the correct element via an attribute, or should I create many tables, one for every element?

```
Links
-elementKey
-url
-elementType
```

or

```
Links1
-elementKey
-url
Links2
-elementKey
-url
```

Comment: Just found out it is a very simple and stupid question... Answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the two solutions are good. Use a **relation table** instead.

More can be found here:
[MySQL multiple foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450365/mysql-multiple-foreign-keys)