# An image table to serve two foreign tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have this `image table`,

```
image_id
image_title
image_description
image_source
```

and I want this `image table` to associate with `page table` and **sometimes with** `comment table`

page table,

```
page_id
...
...
```

comment table,

```
comment_id
...
...
```

Should I put the **foreign key** of `page_id` and `comment_id` in `image` table?

```
image_id
image_title
image_description
image_source
page_id
comment_id
```

Or should I create a `map` table for each purpose?

a `map` table for image and page

```
image_id
page_id
```

and another `map` table for image and comment

```
image_id
comment_id
```

What is the **best practice** for this kind of scenario?

Will the `image` table **get slow** if I use `map` idea when the `image` table row **increase** (this is another main concern)?

Currently I do this,

`image page` table,

```
image_id
image_title
image_description
image_source
page_id
```

`image comment` table,

```
image_id
image_title
image_description
image_source
comment_id
```

but this doesn't look good as I am repeating the columns and it does not appear to be dynamic...

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Sometimes the image is associated with the page and sometimes with comment. The upload image sometimes is for the article itself and sometimes is for the comment under the article.

```
image_id  image_title  page_id  comment_id
1         a            1        NULL
2         b            NULL     1
3         c            1        NULL
4         d            1        NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean by `sometimes`?  It's not very clear what the model *or* the problem is.

Comment: Hi Matt, please see my edit above. Hope it makes sense. thanks.

Comment: "should I create a map table for each purpose?" That depends on whether a page/comment can have multiple images in it; if it's so that would make sense. I've done that for contact-data once, which could get assigned to a user or a company.

Comment: Yes a page/comment should be allowed to have multiple images in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations with the design you have now. For example, an image cannot be related to both a page and a comment. Unless its data is duplicated in the two Image tables. Second and more important, (and as you say, it doesn't look good), you have two tables with almost identical columns and functionality.

So, having one `Image` table and two mapping tables looks much better design. If you later want to store more (and different) information regarding these mappings - for example, you may want to add a last_changed timestamp and a size limitation for `PageImage` (max 100KB per image) and a number limitation for `CommentImage` (max 3 per comment) - you don't have to change the overall design, only these 2 specific mapping tables.

You may, however, find yourself creating a bunch of mapping tables, say one more for `UserImage`, another for `MessageImage` and yet another one for `EmailImage`, all having identical (or almost identical) structure - and this again leads to duplication of code.

To eliminate such duplication, you can use the supertype/subtype pattern. Create a supertype `Entity`, with `Page`, `Comment`, `User`, `Message`, `Email` as subtypes (every one of those child entities will have a Primary Key that is also a Foreign Key to the supertype `Entity`).

Then, your mappings can easily be combined in one `EntityImage` table (with FKs to `Image` and `Entity`).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, ypercube. Can I ask - what is `supertype/subtype pattern`? What difference of it from the `mapping` tables in my OP?

Comment: From another question: [Same data from different entities in Database - Best Practice - Phone numbers example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466163/same-data-from-different-entities-in-database-best-practice-phone-numbers-ex/5471265#5471265)

Comment: The `parties` there is your `Entity`. The `person`, `organization` tables there are your `Page` and `Comment`. After you create your supertype, you can make relationships from other tables to it (1-to-many, 1-to-1, many-to-many, whatever). And thus you are making a relationship to the union of all the subtype entities.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is new to me. Going to spend more time digesting it. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your **Image** table is fine. You should create a **Comment** table and a **Page** table and store the **ImageId** in those tables.

**EDIT: (Didn't read all the comments)**

Based on the requirement that Pages and Comments can have multiple images then the only approach is to creat two linking table one that links the **Comments to Images** and one that links the **Pages to Images**.

Comment: The OP states (in comments): *"a page/comment should be allowed to have multiple images in it."*

Comment: Yikes, then my answer is invalid. In that case there needs to be two linking tables one for Comments and one for Pages. Thanks.