# SQL Server table design with many to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, database-design, many-to-many

I have a database schema that includes the following tables:

- People
- Organisations
- RelationshipTypes

What I want to design is a concept of a relationship type, and then the structure of that relationship. So a person could have a type of relationship with another person or with an organisation. An organisation can have a relationship with another organisation or a person.

I've got the following schema, but I'd like to run it past the community to see if there are any better ideas.

```
CREATE TABLE OrganisationRelationshipTypes
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RelationshipTypeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES RelationshipTypes(ID)
    FromOrganisationID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organisations(ID),
    ToOrganisationID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organisations(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE PersonRelationshipTypes
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RelationshipTypeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES RelationshipTypes(ID),
    FromPersonID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES People(ID),
    ToPersonID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES People(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE OrganisationPersonRelationshipTypes
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RelationshipTypeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES RelationshipTypes(ID)
    FromOrganisationID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organisations(ID),
    ToPersonID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES People(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE PersonOrganisationRelationshipTypes
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RelationshipTypeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES RelationshipTypes(ID)
    FromPersonID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES People(ID),
    ToOrganisationID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Organisations(ID)
)
```

The idea of this is that it covers such scenarios:

- An organisation has done business with another organisation
- A person is another person's father
- An organisation recently hired the person
- A person recently worked for the organisation

This schema seems a little messy, but at the minute I can't think of an alternative.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do those latter two need to be separate tables? Couldn't the relationship type determine whether the relationship is "from" the person and "to" the organisation, or vice versa?

Comment: Have you considered the Party Model?  See [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466163/same-data-from-different-entities-in-database-best-practice-phone-numbers-ex/5471265#5471265)

Comment: How would you evaluate alternative solutions? What criteria should we consider?

Comment: how will you know "A person is another person's father"?  is there something in the RelationshipType table?  can you show the structure of this table as well.

Comment: @MakkyNZ - Yes, the RelationshipType table will contain a description of the relationship such as "Father", or "Past employer".

Comment: @NevilleK - I don't think there are any more scenarios, I think I've got them covered. I was just looking for any alternative schema's to try and replicate what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Party` is often used as a generic term for person or organization, as in "parties in contract" ...

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I like the look of that.

Comment: I like the look of that as well. It's interesting to note that the object labelled "party-type" is a feature of ER modeling, but not of relational modeling. It's an instance of the "gen-spec" pattern, otherwise known as class hierarchy. For the design of a relational model to implement gen-spec, see other questions in "database design". A search on "Class table hierarchy" will give lots of threads.

Answer (score 1):

It looks nice.

I suggest squishing all of the relation tables into one

```
CREATE TABLE RelationShips (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    RelationshipTypeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES RelationshipTypes(ID),
    FromPersonID INT REFERENCES People(ID),
    ToPersonID INT REFERENCES People(ID),
    FromOrganisationID INT REFERENCES Organisations(ID),
    ToOrganisationID INT REFERENCES Organisations(ID)
)
```

This way you can easily filter relationships with just one database lookup. I.e. "Find all relationships to the specific person".
Of course you'll need to remove `NOT NULL` constraints.

Comment: You could add `CHECK` constraints to this definition such that one (and exactly one) `From` column is non-null, and similarly for the `To` columns. Not sure if I'm in favour of the overall design though.

Comment: This is something I was possibly looking at. Avoiding unnecessary calls to the database was a reason why I wasn't particularly happy with the current design.