# Foreign Key Constraint based upon specific values in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys

In my database, I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Category_Dim]
(
    [Id]                  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[__ParentCategoryId] INT 
    ,[Name]               VARCHAR(250)

    ,CONSTRAINT [FK1] FOREIGN KEY ([__ParentCategoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category_Dim] ([Id])
)
```

This allows me to store multiple different kinds of categorical (nested) lists with a root having `__ParentCategoryId = NULL` and, then, have children entered as follows, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Category_Dim (Id, __ParentCategoryId, Name) VALUES
    (1, NULL, 'Dog Breeds'),
    (2, NULL, 'Bird Types'),

    (3, 1, 'Chihuahua'),
    (4, 1, 'Pug'),
    (5, 1, 'Pit Bull'),

    (6, 2, 'Macaw'),
    (7, 2, 'Finch'),
    ... etc
```

In other words, in this case, Ids 3, 4 & 5 are children of 1 (different dog breeds) and 6 & 7 are children of 2 (types of birds).

---

Now, suppose I am trying to create a second table where I want to **only allow dog breeds (children of `Id = 1`) as values** in a column and an error otherwise.

So far, I have the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [Trainers]
(
    [TrainerId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1)
    ,[__DogBreedId] INT NOT NULL
    
    , ...

    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_DogBreeds] FOREIGN KEY ([__DogBreedId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category_Dim] ([Id])
)
```

This has the foreign key constraint, but it allows any `Id` value from `Category_Dim` as my `__DogBreedId`, so a person could put in numbers aside from, in this case, 3-5 as I would want.

Is there a way to accomplish this through a foreign key statement? And, if not, what is the best way to do this or is this a bad idea overall?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can't do it with a foreig key. The other option is to implement a "pre-insert" trigger to validate the relationship, but it's a bit clunky. It begs the question, why do you want this in the first place? I haven't seen a real life app doing it.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the [one description table to rule them all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approach-good). It also sounds similar to EAV - the search for infinite flexibility.

Comment: @SMor, I get your point and I'm left wondering the same thing. I do feel this is just a single category table rather than multiple repetitive tables with simple `Id` and `Name` fields, just differing by name, but I do get the issue this creates... This is a tough one. Either way, I did come up with a solution and posted it, but still left wondering if I'm just creating an anti-pattern here. Thanks.

Comment: @TheImpaler, I updated the question to better explain the question and came up with an answer, but hoping there's a smarter way still to do this. I hope the edit explains my situation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to achieve this was I created a function that returned a `BIT` based upon the `CategoryId` provided being a child of a parent CategoryId:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsChildOfCategory]
(
    @__CategoryId        INT
    ,@__ParentCategoryId INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN CASE
        WHEN EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT Id FROM Category_Dim 
                WHERE __ParentCategoryId = @__ParentCategoryId 
                AND Id = @__CategoryId
            )
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
    END;
GO
```

Then, I added the following check constraint to my table definition:

```
,CONSTRAINT [CHK_IsDogBreed] CHECK ([dbo].[IsChildOfCategory]([__DogBreedId], 1) = 1)
```

This, together with the Foreign Key constraint, seems to do exactly what I want it to do.

**But** I'm really left wondering if this is a terrible pattern to use (everything stored as data in a single category table rather than separate DB tables for each type of data), since this leaves me having to hard-code `Category Ids` like in this check-constraint which exist as data within the DB rather than specific DB objects (In other words, it leaves me needing to seed my DB with very specific values - In this case ensuring `Category Id` 1 = 'Dog Breeds').

So, it did work, but it does leave me questioning if this is a bad idea.

Comment: If you tree depth is greater than one, than this function doesn't work. You will have to write a CTE.

Comment: Also, I don't think it is a problem if you name your table `DogTrainers` and the `Id` for `Dog Breeds` doesn't change. If you are assuming that it will change, why?

Comment: @marcos, agreed re: the CTE - Not a big change and easy enough to implement if that happens, but I don't see it being a case in my specific situation. As for the `Id` for `Dog Breeds`, it does change ('Chihuahia', 'Beagle', etc), their **PARENT ID** would be the same (=`Dog Breed`).

Answer (score 0):

For a single-level hierarchy (node depth = 1) you may be better off by using [supertype-subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a196713%20supertype).

If you do need a tree of a variable node depth then consider using a *closure table*, instead of having the `parent_id` in the same table.
Closure table stores all paths in a tree, so each ancestor-descendant link is a separate row. This way all ancestor/descendants of a given node are exposed. Closure tables are easy to query, but a bit harder to maintain, so it's a trade-off.

```
-- Category CAT exists.
--
category {CAT}
      PK {CAT}


-- Data Sample
  (CAT)
------------------------
  ('Dogs')
, ('Big Dogs')
, ('Small Dogs')  
, ('Chihuahua')
, ('Pug')
, ('Pit Bull')
, ('Birds')
, ('Macaw')
, ('Finch')
```

```
-- Ancestor ANC has descendant DCS
--
category_tree {ANC, DCS}
           PK {ANC, DCS}

FK1 {ANC} REFERENCES category {CAT}
FK2 {DCS} REFERENCES category {CAT}


-- Data Sample, includes ANC=DCS
   (ANC, DCS)
------------------------
  ('Dogs'       , 'Dogs')
, ('Birds'      , 'Birds')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Big Dogs')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Small Dogs')
, ('Big Dogs'   , 'Big Dogs')
, ('Small Dogs' , 'Small Dogs')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Chihuahua')
, ('Small Dogs' , 'Chihuahua')
, ('Chihuahua'  , 'Chihuahua')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Pug')
, ('Small Dogs' , 'Pug')
, ('Pug'        , 'Pug')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Pit Bull')
, ('Big Dogs'   , 'Pit Bull')
, ('Pit Bull'   , 'Pit Bull')
, ('Birds'      , 'Macaw')
, ('Macaw'      , 'Macaw')
, ('Birds'      , 'Finch')
, ('Finch'      , 'Finch')
```

```
-- Trainer TRA trains all descendants of ancestor ANC.
--
trainer {TRA, ANC}
     PK {TRA, ANC}

FK {ANC, ANC} REFERENCES category_tree {ANC, DCS}


-- Data Sample
   (TRA, ANC)
------------------------
  ('Joe'    , 'Dogs')
, ('Jane'   , 'Small Dogs')
, ('Jane'   , 'Finch')
, ('Jill'   , 'Big Dogs')
, ('Jack'   , 'Birds')
, ('John'   , 'Pug')
```

```sql
-- Trainer TRA trains DCS, descendant of ANC.
-- (Resolved to leaf nodes.)
WITH
q_00 AS ( -- leaves only
select ANC, count(1) as cnt 
from category_tree
group by ANC
having count(1) = 1
)
SELECT t.TRA, x.DCS, t.ANC
FROM trainer       AS t
JOIN category_tree AS x ON x.ANC = t.ANC
JOIN q_00 as q ON q.ANC = x.DCS
ORDER BY TRA, t.ANC;
;
```

Returns:

```
TRA     DCS          ANC
----------------------------------
Jack'  'Finch'      'Birds'
Jack'  'Macaw'      'Birds'
Jane'  'Finch'      'Finch'
Jane'  'Pug'        'Small Dogs'
Jane'  'Chihuahua'  'Small Dogs'
Jill'  'Pit Bull'   'Big Dogs'
Joe'   'Pit Bull'   'Dogs'
Joe'   'Pug'        'Dogs'
Joe'   'Chihuahua'  'Dogs'
John'  'Pug'        'Pug'
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

---

---

### SQL to Test

```sql
CREATE TABLE category (
  CAT VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
 
, CONSTRAINT pk_cat PRIMARY KEY (CAT)
);


CREATE TABLE category_tree (
  ANC VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
, DCS VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT pk_ctre  PRIMARY KEY (ANC, DCS)

, CONSTRAINT fk1_ctre FOREIGN KEY (ANC)
              REFERENCES category (CAT)

, CONSTRAINT fk2_ctre FOREIGN KEY (DCS)
              REFERENCES category (CAT)
);


CREATE TABLE trainer (
  TRA VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
, ANC VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT pk_tra PRIMARY KEY (TRA, ANC)

, CONSTRAINT fk1_tra FOREIGN KEY (ANC, ANC)
        REFERENCES category_tree (ANC, DCS)
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO category (CAT)
VALUES
  ('Dogs')
, ('Big Dogs')
, ('Small Dogs')  
, ('Chihuahua')
, ('Pug')
, ('Pit Bull')
, ('Birds')
, ('Macaw')
, ('Finch')
;

INSERT INTO category_tree (ANC, DCS)
VALUES
  ('Dogs'       , 'Dogs')
, ('Birds'      , 'Birds')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Big Dogs')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Small Dogs')
, ('Big Dogs'   , 'Big Dogs')
, ('Small Dogs' , 'Small Dogs')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Chihuahua')
, ('Small Dogs' , 'Chihuahua')
, ('Chihuahua'  , 'Chihuahua')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Pug')
, ('Small Dogs' , 'Pug')
, ('Pug'        , 'Pug')
, ('Dogs'       , 'Pit Bull')
, ('Big Dogs'   , 'Pit Bull')
, ('Pit Bull'   , 'Pit Bull')
, ('Birds'      , 'Macaw')
, ('Macaw'      , 'Macaw')
, ('Birds'      , 'Finch')
, ('Finch'      , 'Finch')
;

INSERT INTO trainer (TRA, ANC)
VALUES
  ('Joe'    , 'Dogs')
, ('Jane'   , 'Small Dogs')
, ('Jane'   , 'Finch')
, ('Jill'   , 'Big Dogs')
, ('Jack'   , 'Birds')
, ('John'   , 'Pug')
;
```

### EDIT

If a whole table should be restricted to just one ancestor then you may:

```
-- Trainer TRA trains dog DCS; (ANC = 'Dogs').
--
dog_trainer {TRA, DSC, ANC}
         PK {TRA, DSC}

FK {ANC, DSC} REFERENCES category_tree {ANC, DCS}

CHECK (ANC = 'Dogs')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I get the idea of the closure table, but I'm still lost as to how this helps with the criteria of having the trainer table only allow `dog` types as values to be inputted. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnBustos So the whole trainer table is allowed only one type?

Comment: Yes, Damir - For example, in my (stupid) example, a trainer only trains dogs, but would never train birds, so you'd want the DB to kick back an error if a bird-type was entered into the corresponding column. I do now get your structure and will give it more thought. I'm just not a fan of the upkeep relating to this (as well as a structure where the value in the entire column will always be `dogs`) over my current structure where it self-references... I do see how each has it's own advantages and disadvantages. Just have to consider which makes more sense in my current architecture. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnBustos, yes having a column with the same values is a trade-off. Same problem exist in supertype/ subtype model. The problem is lack of assertions, as noted in this Q/A: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024799/how-to-bind-users-to-different-organizations-universities-companies-with-diffe