# Database design for startlist of different types of games

Tags: database-design, model, entity-relationship, normalization

I want to design a schema for several games in my application. The games can be of different types and what I want to create is a good design to provide the start list for these games.

The game can be played by individuals or teams and the start list can be in group or as a duel. The start list type gives the game type: (I will use the analogy with sports)

- group of individuals (like a marathon)
- duel of individuals (like in tennis)
- group of teams (like a relay in athletics)
- duel of teams (like in football)

I was thinking at something like this:

**GameEvent**

1. `id`
2. `idGameType`

   1. group individual
   2. duel individual
   3. group team
   4. duel team
3. `idDuel //in case game type==2 or 4`

**Duel**

5. `id`
6. `idGameEvent`
7. `idPlayer1 //in case of gametype==2`
8. `idPlayer2`
9. `idTeam1 //in case of gametype==4`
10. `idTeam2`

**GameGroup** (many-to-many mapping)

11. `id`
12. `idGameEvent`
13. `idPlayer //in case of gametype==1`
14. `idTeam //in case of gametype==3`

Is this solution a good one? There can be another one better? If yes, please explain why.
Other solution(but in am not sure) would be to have tables splitted in based on the 4 types.

**UPDATE**: Except the answers already posted, I found another approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471265/2274471).

```
Player                Participant           Team                    Participation
------                 -------          -------------             --------------
participant_id(PK,FK)--->participant_id   <--- participant_id(PK,FK)  participant_id
participant_type(FK) --->participant_type <--- participant_type(FK)   gameevent_id
birthdate              name                    home_site              result
```

**UPDATE2** The `participant_type` column tells us if the participant is an individual or a team (it will help on the application level to know this). It is used together with `participant_id` in the `Player` and `Team` tables as a constraint.

Comment: You need to ask us a specific question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I edited the post and added the questions.

Comment: You probably mean participant_id not participation_id, the same for type? Can you please describe primary keys of each table and describe what does the "type" column mean?

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. You mean the class-inheritance pattern, that Participant is generalization of both Team & Player... but 1) your case is not generalization pattern but hierarchy pattern. Now you lost the hierarchy Player - Team, i.e. you no longer now which players belong to which team. 2) This design is much more complex (# of tables, query complexity) with no added value over the other designs. You can achieve the much more with one or two table less. Conclusion: I wouldn't go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally agree to Kombajn's suggestions - keeping individuals as teams (this is a very good practice, very often done in clean designes, simplifies things a lot) etc.. However:

1. I think that the many-to-many relationship should be preserved between `Team` and `GameEvent` - teams should be able to participate in more events. I would call this table `Participation`. The advantage is that you can add attributes to each participation (e.g. the result of the team).
2. In case of `Player` - `Team` relationship, the question is whether the player could be part of more teams. If yes, we have many-to-many relationship again and additional table is needed.

The result would look like this:

```
Player       PlayerTeam        Team           Participation         GameEvent
------       ----------        -------        -------------         --------------
id    <----- player_id    .--> id     <------ team_id          ,--> id
name         team_id   --'     name           gameevent_id ---'     game_type
             since                            result                date
                                                                    place
```

Note that the result could be also placed into the GameEvent table, including e.g. a link to the winning team... But I believe placing it into participation table is better. It allows you the same and something more - e.g. store a score and order for all participating teams, not just the winning one.

If you don't want Players to be part of more teams, you can simplify the design, but be aware that it is not very flexible:

```
Player            Team           Participation         GameEvent
------            -------        -------------         --------------
id           ,--> id     <------ team_id          ,--> id
team_id ----'     name           gameevent_id ---'     game_type
name                             result                date
                                                       place
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Most probably I would do in this way. An alternative approach for team-player design would be to have another table called `Participant` with `participant_id` and `participant_type` as columns. Plus the two tables `Player(participant_id, participant_type)` and `Team(participant_id, participant_type)`. Practically, there is one more layer. How bad is this approach?

Comment: @Setilă I don't understand your approach very well. Seems that your tables Player and Team are identical and don't contain their original fields... I think you have some mistakes there. The table Participant serves in similar way as my PlayerTeam?

Comment: I wrote only the primary keys...Player and Team would have their specific columns. This approach is what I have found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5471265/2274471

Comment: OK, so Player has `(participant_id, participant_type)` as a primary key, as well as Team. How can you have the *same* primary key for the Player and Team table?

Comment: sorry. `(participant_id, participant_type)` as the foreign key and `participant_id` as a shared key with `Participant` table.

Comment: @Setilă OK, but I am not sure I understand your design just from this. Could you write a complete scheme to your question in the similar way I did?

Answer (score 1):

Remove table duels. Treat individuals as one-player teams. Let game have many teams. The model will simplify to:

```
GameEvent (id [PK], game_type)
Team (id [PK], game_id [FK: GameEvent])
Player (id [PK], team_id [FK: Team])
```

You will need to validate number of teams in a game and number of players in the team on application level (based on game_type).

Note this allows further extensions: for example let a new game type have four two-player teams.

Comment: I like how simple is your approach. I will think about it but also I would like to ask you if you can find another one. The drawback of this solution is that individuals are treated as one-player teams.

Comment: This is just the data model layer. Your application does not have to present to end users the one-player teams, it can act differently based on the number of players or game_type. Or you might add a flag to Team table (individual Y/N) or number_of_players field to make this check simpler. Whatever suits you best.