# Database design 3rd Normal Form

Tags: database-design

I have a database with many tables, 4 of which are these

1. Payment
2. Credit Card
3. Paypal
4. Bitcoin

Credit Card attributes:

- cardID (PK)
- type
- number
- expireDate
- ...

PayPal attributes:

- paypalID (PK)
- account
- ...

Bitcoin attributes:

- bitcoinID (PK)
- ...

Payment Table attributes:

- amount
- ...
- ...
- cardID (FK)
- paypalID (FK)
- bitcoinID (FK)

A payment can only be paid by either a card/paypal/bitcoin so I am breaking 3rd normal form because if the client uses a card then I know that he didnt use paypal or bitcoin. How can I fix this so that I am not breaking 3rd normal Form.

Comment: Every PayPal transaction is a payment, but not every payment is a PayPal transaction. So the PayPal table should reference the appropriate payment, not the other way around.

Comment: the thing is that am storing there paypal, card, and bitcoin information because the payments are recurring aka monthly payments. So the paypal informations that I store is not a transaction its just the information needed to make a transaction. (hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a *completely* clean way to do this today in SQL, because SQL platforms don't support assertions. (CREATE ASSERTION in the SQL standards) But you *can* design your tables to support sensible constraints, even without support for assertions.

Push the attributes that are common to all scheduled payments "up" into the table "scheduled_payments".

```
create table scheduled_payments (
  pmt_id integer primary key,
  pmt_amount numeric(14, 2) not null
    check (pmt_amount > 0),
  pmt_type char(1) not null
    check (pmt_type in ('b', 'c', 'p')),      -- (b)itcoin, (c)redit card, (p)aypal.
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'x', -- Other columns common to all payment types.
  unique (pmt_id, pmt_type)
);

-- Tables for Bitcoin and PayPal not shown, but they're very similar
-- to this table for credit cards.
create table credit_cards (
  pmt_id integer primary key,
  pmt_type char(1) not null default 'c'
    check (pmt_type = 'c'),
  foreign key (pmt_id, pmt_type) 
    references scheduled_payments (pmt_id, pmt_type),
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'x' -- Other columns unique to credit cards.
);
```

The `primary key`, `not null`, and `check(...)` constraints in "credit_cards" guarantee that every row will have a payment id number and a 'c'. The foreign key constraint guarantees that every row in "credit_cards" will reference a 'c' row in "scheduled_payments".

- [CREATE ASSERTION](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/create-assertion-statement/)
- [Similar design problem related to persons and organizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471265/562459)
- [Similar design problem related to blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970646/562459)