# Question about composite primary keys

Tags: database-design, composite-primary-key, database-integrity

Example table:

```
Ticket
    - id
    - tenant_id
    - foo
TicketItem
    - id
    - tenant_id
    - ticket_id
    - bar
```

Assuming that `id` and `tenant_id` on each table make up composite primary keys, and that `ticket_id` is a foreign key to `Ticket` will this setup protect me from a circumstance where a `TicketItem` has `tenant_id=1` and `ticket_id=5`  where the `Ticket` with `id=5` has `tenant_id=2`? In simpler words, would the database allow me to link rows from 2 tables - each with different `tenant_id` - together, ruining my data, or does it protect me from this?

Also, does the above example seem like a "good" use of a composite primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your `Ticket` table has a primary key on `(TicketID, TenantID)`, then any table referencing the `Ticket` table would also have to reference **both** columns, e.g.

```
TicketItem(TicketID,TenantID) ==> Ticket(TicketID,TenantID)
```

You cannot have a reference to just parts of a (compound) primary key, e.g. you cannot have `TicketID` in `TicketItem` reference the `Ticket` table - you need both parts of a compound primary key in every single foreign key referencing it (one of the major drawbacks of compound indices, in my opinion - it makes joins cumbersome)

Comment: Thanks Mark +1. Clearly I have much to learn regarding composite primary keys. Does this mean that `TicketItem`'s foreign key will be a composite key in itself? Also, does this mean that I can have the same composite primary key in each table (`tenant_id` and `id`) and that when I try to link a `TicketItem` with `tenant_id=2` to a `Ticket` with `tenant_id=1` the database will throw an integrity error? I suppose the reason I'm asking these things is that I don't otherwise see the value of a composite primary key.

Comment: @mark_s - also, would you or wouldn't you avoid using composite fields for the most part (including multi-tenancy like this).

Comment: @orokusaki: by default, I always try to avoid composite keys - they just get hard to use, they negatively affect performance, and they're just a pain. Unless I have a very compelling reason not to, I always use a single column key - and use a surrogate `INT IDENTITY` if no natural key is easily available.

Comment: @marc_s: You said, "You cannot have a reference to just parts of a (compound) primary key". Actually, you can. If ticket.id were declared unique, you could reference ticket.id alone, even if the primary key were (id, tenant_id).

Comment: @catcall: ok, yes - if you can define parts of a PK as unique, then you can reference it separately. But this is a hack - you need to do this explicitly - it's not just possible without this hack. And: **WHY** would you have a composite key, if even a part of your key is already unique?? Wouldn't that part alone be good enough for a PK then??

Comment: @marc_s: Ordinarily, I'd agree with you. But auto-incrementing id numbers are guaranteed to be unique. It's almost a knee-jerk response for some designers to also declare them `UNIQUE`. I'd call that a mistake here, but certainly not a hack. Why have a reducible composite key?  To work around limitations in SQL. Multi-tenant, shared schema designs require it. (http://iablog.sybase.com/kleisath/index.php/2009/11/multi-tenant-database-architecture-part-5/) So do supertype/subtype designs. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-problem)

Comment: @Catcall - is there a way to make an integer field that is part of a composite primary key auto-increment with regards to the other part of the primary key (ie, When I create `Tenant [id=6]` there are already 325 `Ticket`s in the database. I don't want the first `Ticket` that `Tenant [id=6]` creates to be `Ticket [tenant_id=6, id=326]`. I'd rather it be `Ticket [tenant_id=6, id=1]`, if the `id` field doesn't need to be unique on its own. Is this possible?

Comment: @orokusaki: It's not possible using only DDL. You'd have to code a stored procedure or a function to do the hard work. The way I look at it, a 32-bit unsigned integer gives me 4 billion rows, a 64-bit integer gives me 18 quintillion rows (?) and a GUID gives me, um, a lot more rows. I think I'd probably just pick one of those, and live with it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - the foreign key in TicketItem should reference both the id and tenant_id fields in the Ticket table. A foreign key should reference a primary key - if you were to only reference the id, you would not be referencing the primary key of the ticket table, as the Ticket table contains a composite key that includes both the id and the tenant_id fields.

If you have a foreign key in TicketItem that references the Ticket table's primary key (both id and tenant_id), then you will not be able to insert/update a record in the TicketItem table that does not have a corresponding id + tenant_id record in the Ticket table (this is what you desire).

TicketItem:
Foreign Key should reference ticket_id -> Ticket.id AND tenant_id -> Ticket.tenant_id

As far as a "good" use of the composite key - it depends on your design/requirements, but there is not anything "bad" about it.

Answer (score 0):

"where the Ticket with id=5 has tenant_id=2"

Based on that wording ("the ticket"), is there only ever one ticket with id = 5? If so, that's your primary key and using the tenant_id to make a composite key is just making things more cumbersome.

If you can have multiple id = 5 then you can use the composite key, and yes it'll need to match both correctly in order for the reference to work.