# Polymorphic vs HABTM relationships for a tagging system

Tags: database, has-and-belongs-to-many, relationships, polymorphism

I am currently making a database for a rails application. This schema involves three models: Photo, Object and Tag. Both photos and objects need to be "taggable".

- Tags are unique
- Tags can belong to a Photo, or an Object, or both

Rails offers a polymorphic association which results in tags having a belongs_to relationship with both Photo and Object; however it does not allow a Tag to belong belong to **both**.

One might solve this by having two independent HABTM relationships for 'tags to photos' and 'tags to objects'.

I was wondering if there was more efficient way of achieving this; or if perhaps I am approaching the problem from the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags are a way of saying something about a thing.

It might not make sense to use a single set of tags to say something about every kind of thing. I can imagine tags like "1024x768" and "shot-with-Olympus-camera" being useful if you're trying to say something about a photo, but not really useful if you're trying to say something about an object.

Let's say I use a tag like "blue" to refer to both a photo and to an object. Does {photo_id, "blue"} mean the same thing as {object_id, "blue"}? I don't think it does.

It seems to me the most efficient solution is to use one set of tags to say something about photos, and another set of tags to say something about objects.  It's also likely to be more friendly to your users.

Comment: I definitely see what you're saying and it is a very valid point. Although in our specific situation (if we were to divulge more about what a Photo and an Object really is) it is actually necessary.

Comment: When you hide what you're talking about, you reduce the odds of getting the right answer. If *Photo* and *Object* aren't quite the same, but aren't utterly different, then you'd just associate the tags with the supertype. See the accepted answer and extensive comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-problem