# Creating a seamless pattern with CSS on the web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a seamless CSS pattern on the web.
I know this is totally nonsense and non-practical at all.
But it is just for the sake of having fun.

http://codepen.io/vennsoh/pen/iFKyo

I have done creating my first tile.
Now I am thinking of a way to repeat it to fill up the whole background.

Can I complete this feat by just using HTML and CSS?
Or must I use javascript to complete this?

-

Here are my steps if using javascript, correct me or suggest better ways:

1. Calculate current browser width and height.
2. A single tile is (150x150), I will just need to create as many div(s) to cover the whole screen.

-

I might want to make things move around, each polygon changes color, etc. It won't be static. I am not looking for a background-image solution.

Thanks,
Venn.

Comment: interesting concept. in a way, you're trying to repeat a div all over the webpage?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just use a repeating background image? I can't think of a good reason not to do it that way, and you haven't given us any clues as to what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sometimes people are just weird, there are people out there who create illustrations in MS Paint just for fun. I just want to test things out. (:

A seamless background pattern that will fill up the whole screen.

Comment: We can't possibly help you with ideas you MIGHT want to implement. Please give us a concrete problem and some code you've actually tried. This is a site for programmers with coding issues, not for creative types with visionary ambitions that outstretch their technical know-how. Voting to close.

Comment: "fun" no i dont want fun here, I always look for solutions to my problems.

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger for the helpful comment. Yes, I am still new with web programming. (: I guess I will have to take a jab at the code myself. I don't feel there is anything wrong with doing things differently in hope to achieve a creative result. It might not work at all but it is worth trying.

Comment: I certainly do want *some* level of fun in here. And I'm sure others do too. Otherwise, why would the [pile of socks question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently) attract so much attention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is possible with only html and css. The problem in your example is that every part of background will overlap when you set `background-repeat` property because they have different size, so you just need to  resize and position your shapes differently. The easy way to do this in your case is set one `background-size` for every shape (size of desired complete pattern) and change their position accordingly.

I've modified part of your example to give you an idea of how it should look like: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pnxyd

Comment: Thanks! I have learned something (:

Comment: Nice. Better than my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just add,

```
float:left;
```

to the css, and then just make multiple copies of the div, just like here...http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rlDqh

I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: I think that the problem is the asker wants only to use a single div

Comment: :L yup I realised that after I had answered..:D still searching for a way to do so...

Comment: This is the obvious solution, and might not be what the OP ultimately wanted, but it might be the only feasible way to accomplish that with just CSS. +1