# Walking a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph

I have a directed acyclic graph and an origin vertex `v` in that graph.
How can I visit all the vertices that are reachable from `v`, in such a way that if I visit `v1` I already visited all the vertices that have and edge to `v1`?

Example:

```
/-----V
A->B->C
```

Starting from `A`, `C` must be visited after `B`.
I tried just doing a BFS and checking the parents of each vertex and if they are not visited re-add it for later, but that proved too slow, and I believe can be `O(v^2)`.

It might help to know that the graph is somewhat binary, each vertex will be pointed to by at most two vertices. In the other direction, each vertex points to a lot of vertices.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No, algorithm questions are perfectly on topic. [example1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881/572670) [example2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22342854/572670) [example3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3492302/572670). They can be translated to any language, and directly connect to software problems. The OP has also shown an effort to solve it himself.

Comment: @amit I feel like there is a lot of overlap between what's considered on-topic at Stack Overflow ("a software algorithm"), Computer Science ("algorithms, models of computation"), and Programmers ("algorithm and data structure concepts"), all quoted from their "on-topic" pages.  In my opinion, if you can't tag a question with either a programming language (e.g. C), or environment (e.g. POSIX), then it's better suited for on of the other sites. This question could be answered and proven without writing a single line of code ("programming"). I've retracted my vote on precedent, but I don't agree.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart There is a tag with 7k questions, [language-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/language-agnostic?show=all&sort=newest), which is considered on-topic. All the questions in my examples are not related to any specific programming language, yet are very related to programming and were really loved by the community, so I really disagree with you on this.

Comment: I'm sure there's a meta post where this debate rages on, but I'm unable to find it at the moment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The canonical meta post we Programmers users like to link everyone is http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow Personally, my gut feeling is that this question is on topic for both SO and P.SE.

Comment: @Ixrec So in your opinion, would you prefer this at Programmers or SO?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If I was asking this myself, I would pick Programmers, but I don't think there's any need to migrate this off SO.

Comment: This question is fine on many Stack Exchange sites, **including Stack Overflow**. It should not be migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

First, do a topological sort, and get the order of the vertices in the graph according to this sort, let it be `v1,v2,...,vn`.

Using a BFS, you can leave only vertices that are reachable from `v`, (filter the others out), and iterate them in the order of the topological sort.

This is `O(|V|+|E|)`, which is in your case is `O(|V|)` (the relaxation `each vertex will be pointed to by at most two vertices` suggests `|E| <= 2|V|`, and thus `O(|V|+|E|) <= O|V|+2|V|) = O(3|V|) = O(|V|)`