# foreign key from one column to two columns of different table by condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have tree tables MySQL:

articles table contains:

```
id int
title varchar(255)
...
```

news table contains:

```
id int
title varchar(255)
...
```

comments table contains:

```
id int
content text
type tinyint(1)  //this column holds 0 if this comment for news and holds 1 for article
fid  int         // this column holds id of article or news
```

how can I make foreign key from comments table to articles and news. 
I mean how can implement this in MySQL query:

```
if type=0 then
 FOREIGN KEY (fid) REFERENCES news(id)

if type=1 then
 FOREIGN KEY (fid) REFERENCES articles(id)
```

Comment: What does differentiate an article from a news apart from the type?

Comment: news has its own field such as reporter, photographer, editor, ...
but articles has different fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database design - articles, blog posts, photos, stories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-articles-blog-posts-photos-stories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have proper PK-FK relationships I'd suggest to have a superset table (lets call it `posts`). In that case your schema might look like

```
CREATE TABLE posts 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  type TINYINT(1)
);

CREATE TABLE articles
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR (255),
  article_property VARCHAR(128),
  -- other article specific attributes
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES posts (id)
);

CREATE TABLE news
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR (255),
  reporter VARCHAR(128),
  -- other news specific attributes
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES posts (id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INT NOT NULL,
  content TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id)  
);
```

To populate `id`s when inserting new articles and news you can make use of triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_article_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO posts (type) VALUES (1);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_news_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON news
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO posts (type) VALUES (0);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5998/1)** demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can read about foreign key constraints [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), and you will note that only one table is allowed.

One work-around is to have separate columns for the separate ids:

```
id int
content text
type tinyint(1)   //this column holds 0 if this comment for news and holds 1 for article
articleid  int
newsid int
. . . 
foreign key (articleid) references articles(id)
foreign key (newsid) references news(id)
```

In fact, you can dispense with the `type` and add in a constraint (implemented by a trigger) that only one id can be populated at any given time.