# How to prevent that two references share the same primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one common table that is referenced by two other tables in a database. Primary key of that two other tables is also a foreign key that points to a value of a primary key of common table.

I was wondering is there a way, MySQL could prevent that both tables have a same value as a reference?
My idea is something like this:

[image: logins instance should be only in one table (students or professors)]

Login row should be referenced in one of two tables (students or professors), but not in both.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your purpose. Can you show an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I think this may be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4969133/743382 (and if so, the answer there looks good to me), but I too am not sure if I am reading your question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE common (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (id, type)
);

INSERT INTO common (id, type) VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B');

CREATE TABLE typeA (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  FOREIGN KEY (id, type) REFERENCES common(id, type)
);

INSERT INTO typeB (id, type) VALUES (1, 'A'); -- OK
INSERT INTO typeB (id, type) VALUES (2, 'A'); -- FAIL

CREATE TABLE typeB (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'B',
  FOREIGN KEY (id, type) REFERENCES common(id, type)
);

INSERT INTO typeB (id, type) VALUES (1, 'B'); -- FAIL
INSERT INTO typeB (id, type) VALUES (2, 'B'); -- OK
```

You need some way to enforce `type` to the right value in each child table.  For example a trigger, or another foreign key to a lookup table.  MySQL does not support `CHECK` constraints in any storage engine.