# Supertype/Subtype references to catalog tables?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a super-type/sub-type relationship in my database.  The plan is to use something like [this design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970646/2886575).

In the design referenced above, they have a "type" column that is shared between the super and sub types.  The number of sub-types in our db model will be constantly expanding over time, so I would like to maintain functions that allow me to programmatically `JOIN` against the correct subtypes.

I occurs to me that one possibility is to create a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the supertype that `REFERENCE`s the `pg_catalog.pg_class` table.  This forces my types to be table-like references, and would allow me to programmatically find the correct tables to `JOIN` against given any number of rows from the supertype.

OTOH, I'm skeptical about tying into the `pg_catalog` because I have no idea how the guts of the system works, and whether these rows are reliable or will randomly `DELETE CASCADE` my stuff or who knows what.  Also, I'm not sure how I might design these `REFERENCE`s to maintain data integrity between the `type` columns and the `pg_class` tables.

Here's the thought for the design:

```
----------------------------------
| Super                          |
----------------------------------
| [PK]  id int                   |
| [FK (pg_class.oid)]  type int  |
| subtype_id int                 |
----------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
| SubTemplate                                      |
----------------------------------------------------
| [PK]  id int                                     |
| type int  CHECK ????                             |
| [FK (id, type) -> (Super.subtype_id, Super.type) |
----------------------------------------------------
```

How can I create the `CHECK` constraints to maintain data integrity against the `pg_class` table, so that, given that my supertype, subtype and pg_class are in-sync at time t=0, they remain in-sync about which tables are which (or throw an error when trying to perform an operation that would make them out-of-sync)?  Also, are there any other pitfalls regarding `REFERENCE`ing the `pg_class` table that I should be aware of?